# SQL Server: Return row numbers while keeping DISTINCT in effect

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query returns 20 records, which is the entire table:

```
SELECT 
    [This]
   ,[That]
   --, [Unique_ID]
FROM
    MyTable
```

This query returns **5** records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT   -- <<< DISTINCT
    [This]
   ,[That]
   --, [Unique_ID]
FROM
    MyTable
```

If I show row numbers using `ROW_NUMBER()`, the `DISTINCT` keyword is defeated; I'm back to **20** records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT   -- <<< DISTINCT now has no effect
    [This]
   ,[That]
   --, [Unique_ID]
   ,row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [This] )
FROM
    MyTable
```

How can I get SQL Server to display 5 rows with row numbers?

Comment: Explanation is good, but show us some sample data and expected result to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `group by` to the query.

`group by` is evaluated before the `select`, so it removes duplicates and the row numbers can be assigned then.

```
SELECT 
[This]
,[That]
,row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [This] )
FROM MyTable
group by [This],[That]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
;WITH A
AS (SELECT DISTINCT
          [This]
        , [That]
    FROM   MyTable)
SELECT [This]
     , [That]
     , row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [This])
FROM   MyTable;
```

the Common table expression first returns all distinct permutations of [This], [That] and then the query will assign a row number to each returned row.